# Does my Water Genasi Fighter have any cantrips?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation

I created a Water Genasi Fighter, which backstory is he's a pirate.

With rules as written, what cantrips (if any) should this character have?

Comment: Have you read the Elemental Evil Player's Companion for the rules in creating Water Genasi?

Comment: This site has a one question per post policy, so I've edited your post to only ask one of the questions you had here. I encourage you to ask the other one separately.

Comment: This question seems to be related to your second question about Primordial: [Does knowing Primordial mean you understand all the different languages of elementals?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/64425/23064)

Answer (score 14):

The [Elemental Evil Player's Companion](http://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/EE_PlayersCompanion.pdf), which is the source for Water Genasi as playable characters, says that:

> You know the *shape water* cantrip (see chapter 2).